# VBA - update cells in column D if value is entered in column A. If the value is then deleted from column A then also delete from column D

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a sales sheet in excel for a point of sale. I need:

1. When a barcode is entered into cell A5 onwards, I would like cell D5 onwards to update with a default quantity of '1', and
2. If the barcode is then removed, the quantity should be cleared too.

I am able to achieve #1 but not #2. I have the below code so far, can anyone help?

```
Sub SetQuantity()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 5 To LastRow
    If Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & i).Value) Then
        Range("D" & i).Value = 1
     Else: DeleteQuantity
    End If
Next i

End Sub

Sub DeleteQuantity()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 5 To LastRow
    If Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then
        Range("D" & i).Value = ""
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the colon ':' actually in your code: Else: DeleteQuantity ?

Comment: Yes it updated with the colon automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would avoid all the looping and might work better -

```
Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A5:A" & lastrow)) Is Nothing Then
    If IsEmpty(Target) Then
        Target.Offset(, 3) = vbNullString
    Else: Target.Offset(, 3) = 1
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

You'd just place it in the sheet module for the sheet you want to watch.

Comment: Thanks! This one worked perfectly! You are a star :)

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in the sheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Rows.Count = 1 And Target.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        If Not IsEmpty(Target.Value) Then
            Cells(Target.Row, 4) = 1
        Else
            Cells(Target.Row, 4).ClearContents
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This one worked as well, appreciate the help :)